# Why so many questions in the re-open queue?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I just took a look at the review queues and noticed 150+ questions in the reopen queue. Normally there are no more than a handful here.

I started working through them and not one was a serious candidate for re-opening. Apart from two or three that had been edited, none was even remotely on-topic.

It looks like someone has voted mechanically to reopen a whole load of entirely arbitrary and unrelated closed questions.

I've used up my 20 reviews for this queue, but it seems to me that a moderator should take a look at what is going on.

Comment: They adjusted the criteria for "popular questions" which automatically feed into the Reopen Votes queue after closure, which caused a bunch of new questions to be eligible. While most of them are no longer appropriate for our site, there are some pretty good gems in there that shouldn't be closed. So don't blow them all off just because there's a big number.

Comment: It seems from Shog9's linked post that someone is indeed fiddling. I guess I'll just keep batting down the junk until it settles down again.

Comment: Shog needs to start warning us about these so we don't freak out everytime the number jumps :)